# Re-rendering an EditText when typing fast

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, text-rendering, spannablestring

I have the Editable, and I perform replace on it without firing `TextWatcher.onTextChanged()`
like this, where ed is my editable:

```
Object[] o = ((SpannableStringBuilder)ed).getSpans(0,contStr.length(),TextWatcher.class);
((SpannableStringBuilder)ed).removeSpan(o[1]);
SpannableStringBuilder test = ((SpannableStringBuilder)s).replace();// I replace whatever was typed here, like re-rendering
((SpannableStringBuilder)ed).setSpan(o[1],0,contStr.length(),SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Now, when I type fast, my `TextWatcher.onTextChanged()` is giving a wrong parameter for Charsequence.

If I type T-E-S-T really fast,

`TextWatcher.onTextChanged()` is giving me 
T
TTE
TTETES
TTETESTEST

If I type slowly, the re-rendering works fine, though. Please advice how to do re-rendering.

Comment: How is this being tested? On an emulator?

Comment: I'm running this on a tablet.